# Redirect all type of exceptions and stdout logs in a file during test execution - Python 3

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, stderr

My goal is to have a file with the results from my unit tests including any exceptions logged that arose.

I am executing my python test script using `pytest` which generates an xml file with the exact details i want. The problem is that this file is generated right after the execution of the test finishes and not during its execution like I want.

Here is the command I execute my test with:

`python -m  pytest test_signout.py --junitxml ./results/TestsOut.xml -vs`

I have tried to redirect the `stdout` to a file with success but of course this doesn't contain any details related to exceptions such as assertion errors that I want to get.

I have tried the same method for `stderr` but the file stays empty.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
@contextmanager
def redirected_stdout(filename):
    original_stderr = sys.stderr
    sys.stderr = open(filename, 'at')
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stderr = original_stderr
```

The way I am using this method is by adding the following command at the start of each of my methods and I then include all of my code within this:

```
with redirected_stdout("./results/TestsOut.log"):
```

Is there a way I could get both `stderr` and `stdout` logged during runtime or is there another way to achieve what I want?

After I generate this file I am planning as the last step of my test to read it and pass it to the test management solution I use.

---

*UPDATE*:
I have changed `stderr` to `stdout` and I have added `file=sys.stdout` at the end of all print statements that are located in `except` clauses and now these data get printed in the file I want. I don't get the whole output by at least I get the exceptions. If there is a better way to do this please let me know.

Comment: How do you know it's not working? What if instead of `yield` you had `raise RuntimeError('Some error message!')`

Comment: I made my test fail to check the file and it was empty. i have tried now with the `RuntimeError` and nothing was written in the file. I have made a change: I added `, file=sys.stdout` at the end of all my prints within `except` and now they get printed in the file if I use the `stdout` instead of `srderr`. I don't get the whole output by at least I get the exception.

Comment: Might be a silly question, but are you sure the code you're testing is wrapped by the context manager?

Comment: I am not so sure but what I did was to add all of my method's code under `with redirected_stdout("./results/TestsOut.log"):` in all of my test methods, setUp and tearDown methods.. So probably yes.. Do you think the solution I have found could be improved somehow ? I get the exceptions in my log file now, but it would be nicer to get also the part of code that broke like i see it in the console logs.